# Hibernate wont save more than 15 objects during one transaction

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

It saves 15 objects and then just goes into an infinite loop, doing nothing. Nothing is outputted to the console.

This is the code:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = null;
try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        for (Persistable persistable: persistables) {
           session.save(persistable);
        }

        transaction.commit();
    }
    catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (transaction != null) transaction.rollback();
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

I'm using the standard jdbc mysql connector with the standard properties and hbm2ddl set to "create". I resolved it by looping through the objects 15 at a time but I would prefer not to do that in the future.

Comment: It should work . You should not have to limit it to 15. Have you put a debug point and checked why is it behaving the way you think it is for more than 15 ?

Comment: Is autoflush enabled?

Comment: Is it possible that one of your `persistables` has a cyclic loop amongst it's object 'tree'? Does it 'stop' on the same object or a different 15th object each time?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe autoflush is enabled, try to flush the session in the loop.

```
    for (Persistable persistable: persistables) {
       session.save(persistable);
       session.flush();
    }
```

If this works, transactions may not be used, check the jdbc-version.